# Remove cpt slug from url and use custom taxonomy instead breaks all other cpt

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

Im trying to do so, it works but also affects all other cpt (404 for all cpt but not resources one)

this is what I have

In the cpt definition

```
...

        'rewrite' => array(
                      'slug' => 'resource/%resource_type%',
                       'with_front' => false
                     )
...
```

the post link filter

```
// Rewrite urls of resources and put category on url
function wpa_course_post_link( $post_link, $id = 0 ){
    $post = get_post($id);  
    if ( is_object( $post ) ){
        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'resource_type' );
        
        if(get_post_type($post->ID) == 'resource' ) {
            if( $terms ){
                return str_replace( 'resource/%resource_type%', $terms[0]->slug, $post_link );
            }else{
                return home_url( "/resource/".$post->post_name );
            }
        }else{
            return $post_link; 
        }
    }
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpa_course_post_link', 1, 3 );
```

and the problem here, the rewrite rule, if I comment this action all works but the resources does not(404), and if I uncomment this resources works (with the custom url) but all the other cpt does not (404)... so i dont know

```
function resource_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^(.*)/(.*)/?$',
        'index.php?post_type=resource&resource_type=$matches[1]&name=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
        
}
add_action( 'init', 'resource_rewrite_rules' );
```

any help?